# Export files to relative path in R

Tags: r, error-handling, export

I'm not sure what is going on in my R script when I try to export a .csv file to a pre-given path it gives me an error message. Maybe someone can point me at the mistake that I'm doing. Probably it's a stupid minor thing but I just can't see it.

Here is the R script:

```
set.seed(222)
val1 <- rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 8, sd = 2)
val2 <- rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 10, sd = 2)
xval <- c(val1, val2)
g <- c(rep("g1", 10000),rep("g2", 10000))
xdata <- data.frame(g, xval)
xdata
path <- "Users/MikeyMouse/Desktop/ExpensesOverview/"
write_csv(x = xdata, path = paste0(path, "Data/generated_dataset.csv"))
```

The error that I receive says:

"Error in open.connection(path, "wb") : cannot open the connection
   In addition: Warning message:
   In open.connection(path, "wb") :
   cannot open file [path's name]: No such file or directory`"

I used `getwd()` in order to check the dir's name and it's correct ("Users/MikeyMouse/Desktop/ExpensesOverview/").

All suggestions and improvements are highly appreciated.

Comment: If the path is your current working directory, perhaps adding a dot+slash in front  will work. lose tha path... write_csv(x = xdata, path = "./Data/generated_dataset.csv")

Comment: Does the `"Data/"` folder exist?

Comment: Yes, the `Data` folder exists. I added the dot+slahs but received another error that the function `write_csv` couldn't be found.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you include root in your path (i.e. it begins with "/" in ubuntu or "C:/" in windows), the function will assume that it is a relative path found in your working directory. Just use:

```
write_csv(x = xdata, path = "Data/generated_dataset.csv")
```

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work. I get an error saying `function write_csv couldn't be found`.

Comment: @user3832272 Have you loaded the required libraries?

Comment: You could try write.csv instead of write_csv